# Need help understanding the sort() c++ function weird behavior

Tags: c++, sorting

I have a comparator function that  compares two strings which represent numbers that have no leading zeros, eg "123" or "5".

```
bool comp(string s1,string s2){
    if(s1.size()!=s2.size())
        return s1.size()<s2.size();

    int i=0;
    while(i<s1.size() && s1[i]==s2[i])
        i++;

    if(i==s1.size())
        return true;

    return s1[i]<s2[i]; 
}
```

Along with a vector of strings nums I use the sort() function like this:

```
sort(nums.begin(),nums.end(),comp);
```

And this function will work for this vector:
`{"5","5","5","5","5","5","5","5","5","5","5","5","5","5","5","5"}`

But if I add one more "5" to the vector it throws this:

> terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::length_error'
>
> what():  basic_string::_M_create

What is going on here?

Comment: please post a [mcve]

Comment: `if(i==s1.size()) return true;` is wrong, it should be `false;`. you have UB in both of your test even if in one case, it seems to works.

Comment: Yeah that seems to work, thank you.

Comment: if you are surprised by the fact that adding an element is changing the sort behavior, that's a really normal fact. 
the code checks the number of element and it selects the right algorithm to use

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your comparer doesn't respect [strict weak ordering](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weak_ordering#Strict_weak_orderings),

equality checked by

```
if (i == s1.size())
    return true;
```

should be

```
if (i == s1.size())
    return false;
```

Alternatively, using [`<tuple>`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/header/tuple) facility ensures strict weak ordering:

```
bool comp(const std::string& s1, const std::string& s2)
{
    return std::forward_as_tuple(s1.size(), s1)
         < std::forward_as_tuple(s2.size(), s2);
}
```